# Issue with catching backspace with TextWatcher

Tags: android, textwatcher

I use TextWatcher because I want to get the string on the fly.

I enter qw in an EditText. Then I do backspace to get a zero  length string. The issue is that when I have left q then the before method is just called. Any idea why?

```
03-05 11:19:10.549 22390-22390/com.narb.check I/TRT changed: q
03-05 11:19:10.589 22390-22390/com.narb.check I/TRT after: q
03-05 11:19:19.359 22390-22390/com.narb.check I/TRT before: q
03-05 11:19:19.359 22390-22390/com.narb.check I/TRT changed: qw
03-05 11:19:19.359 22390-22390/com.narb.check I/TRT after: qw

first backspace

03-05 11:19:48.679 22390-22390/com.narb.check I/TRT before: qw
03-05 11:19:48.679 22390-22390/com.narb.check I/TRT changed: q
03-05 11:19:48.679 22390-22390/com.narb.check I/TRT after: q

second backspace (to get a null string)

03-05 11:20:41.379 22390-22390/com.narb.check I/TRT before: q
```

Here is my code:

```
   edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit)
        {
            ip_host = mEdit.toString();
            Log.i("TRT after",mEdit.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
            Log.i("TRT before",s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            Log.i("TRT changed",s.toString());
        }

    });
```

and my EditText:

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trt_edt"
        android:hint="IP address or hostname"
        android:textSize="@dimen/a_normal"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/trt_start"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/trt_start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: It is working normally. it should behave like that. what do you want from that?

Comment: How do I know I entered backspace on the last char. I would have expected that onTextChanged is called? So I need to implement some kind of flag/counter?

Comment: yes, you need to do that(simply check if after text size is lower than before text size). you expect `onTextChanged` call, it is called. also `beforeTextChanged and `beforeTextChanged` also called because the **Text Changed**.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you right. If I hit backspace on the last char, only beforeTextChanged as normal because one char is left BUT I receive NO call from onTextChanged.

Comment: `void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, 
                int start, 
                int before, 
                int count)`
This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had length before. It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback.

Comment: so tell me how do you expect that onTextChanged called? onTextChanged (Null,1,1,-1)?

Comment: Let me do more test based on your input and I'll get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. I agree that this is odd behaviour. Even for afterTextChanged the event is not fired when deleting the last character. I would have expected the event to fire with the Editable.toString() as "".